# AFHTTPSessionManager not deallocating

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, afnetworking-2

### Update

After posting this as an issue to the AFNetworking repo, turns out this is in fact a usage issue on my part. Per the response to my issue:

> NSURLSession retains its delegate (i.e. AFURLSessionManager). Call invalidateSessionCancelingTasks: to ensure that sessions finalize and release their delegate.

So, long story short: If you are using `AHTTPSessionManager` in the manner described below, make sure to call `invalidateSessionCancelingTasks:` to ensure that sessions finalize and release their delegate

### Original Question

I have a subclassed `AFHTTPSessionManager` called `GTAPIClient` that I am using to connect to my REST API. I realize the docs state to use as a singleton but there are a few cases where I need to gin up a new instance. However, it seems that whenever I do so, the object is never deallocated. Currently, `GTAPIClient` literally does nothing except `NSLog` itself when deallocated. 
Here's some sample code that demonstrates the behavior

### GTAPIClient.m

```
@implementation GTAPIClient
- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"Dealloc: %@", self);    
}

@end
```

### GTViewController.m

```
#import "GTBaseEntityViewController.h"

//Models
#import "GTBaseEntity.h"

//Clients
#import "GTAPIClient.h"

@interface GTBaseEntityViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, weak) GTAPIClient *client;
@property (nonatomic, weak) GTBaseEntity *weakEntity;

@end

@implementation GTBaseEntityViewController

- (IBAction)makeClient:(id)sender {

    self.client = [[GTAPIClient alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"I just made an API client %@", self.client);

    //Another random object assigned to a similar property, just to see what happens.
    self.weakEntity = [[GTBaseEntity alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"I just made a random object %@", self.weakEntity);

}

- (IBAction)checkClient:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"Client: %@", self.client);
    NSLog(@"Entity: %@", self.weakEntity);

}

@end
```

### NSLog output

Fire `makeClient:`

```
//It seems to me that both NSLog's should return (null) as they are assigning to a weak property
2014-06-22 16:41:39.143 I just made an API client <GTAPIClient: 0x10b913680, baseURL: (null), session: <__NSCFURLSession: 0x10b915010>, operationQueue: <NSOperationQueue: 0x10b9148a0>{name = 'NSOperationQueue 0x10b9148a0'}>
2014-06-22 16:41:39.144 I just made a random object (null)
```

Fire `checkClient`

```
//Again, both NSLog's should return null for the two objects. However...client is still around. Also, it's overridden dealloc method never fired.

2014-06-22 16:44:43.722  Client: <GTAPIClient: 0x10b913680, baseURL: (null), session: <__NSCFURLSession: 0x10b915010>, operationQueue: <NSOperationQueue: 0x10b9148a0>{name = 'NSOperationQueue 0x10b9148a0'}>
2014-06-22 16:44:43.723 Entity: (null)
```

For reference, I am using v2.3.1 of AFNetworking. Compiler is warning me that assigning retained object to weak property will release after assignment - which is correct, and functions as expects with my random object. There is nothing else going on in the app. No other view controllers, no other methods on the `GTAPIClient`, all singleton functionality is removed. Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replicating your scenario and running it through Instruments shows that AFURLSessionManagers are retained by the NSURLSessions they create, as AFURLSessionManager acts as the delegate for every NSURLSession created. This creates a retain cycle and thus the AFHTTPSessionManager cannot be released. Whether this is a bug in either library or not a bug at all, I'm not sure. You may want to report it on the AFNetworking GitHub page (https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).

Comment: Very good. I posted an issue to the repo:(https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/2149)

Answer (score 10):

Posting the response from Mattt Thompson here to assist future readers:

> `NSURLSession` [retains its delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURLSession/delegate) (i.e. `AFURLSessionManager`). Call `invalidateSessionCancelingTasks:` to ensure that sessions finalize and release their delegate.

If, like many apps, your app uses a singleton Session Manager and one URL Session for your entire app, then you don't need to worry about this.

Answer (score 1):

```
__weak typeof(manager) weak_manager = manager;
[manager requestWithMethod:method URLString: uri parameters:param
         success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
                if (completion) {
                    completion(YES, responseObject, task.response);
                }
                [weak_manager invalidateSessionCancelingTasks:YES];
         }
         failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
                if (completion) {
                    completion(NO, error, task.response);
                }
                [weak_manager invalidateSessionCancelingTasks:YES];
         }];
```